# Magento Quick Search - Search on short description attribute not working

Tags: php, search, magento, indexing

I have developed a site with magento. I have enabled “Short Description” attribute for both quick search and Advance search.

Now, when i search any word for example “Wool” which in product’s short description, no result comes. Is quick search have some issue with “Short Description”.

I want this on since every product has short description and this search is not working at all.

Jeff

Answer (score 5):

Have you reindexed so that the new attribute is included in the index?  Go to System>Index Management, select Catalog Search Index and then Reindex Data.

Comment: Oh wow... It is working now. Thanks Jonathan for your help. You have saved my day. Thanks.

Comment: Be sure and accept the solution Jonathan gave if it fixed your issue.  See FAQ for more details. http://stackoverflow.com/faq